# Where to put Firebase Database read in NodeJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to call this piece of React JS code inside my web app. The thing is though that I tried calling it inside the `render()` method but that leads to an infinite loop. I then tried to call it inside a `constructor()` and to `componentWillUpdate()` but the functions are not fired there.

```
listenForNewPins() {
  console.log("listening for new segnalazioni...");
  var ref = firebase.database().ref("segnalazioni");
  ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    console.log("new value under segnalazioni:");
    console.log("fetched:", snapshot.val());
    console.log("---------------------------------");
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();

      if (typeof childData.luogo === "undefined") {
        console.log("undefined, ignoring...");
      } else {
        console.log("Using child data:", childData);
        this.setState({ markers: [...this.state.markers, childData] });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

This is the complete component:

```
import React from "react";
import CustomMap from "./components/CustomMap";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import firebase from "./Firebase";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    markers: []
  };

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.listenForNewPins();
  }

  listenForNewPins() {
    console.log("listening for new segnalazioni...");
    var ref = firebase.database().ref("segnalazioni");
    ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
      console.log("new value under segnalazioni:");
      console.log("fetched:", snapshot.val());
      console.log("---------------------------------");
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();

        if (typeof childData.luogo === "undefined") {
          console.log("undefined, ignoring...");
        } else {
          console.log("Using child data:", childData);
          this.setState({ markers: [...this.state.markers, childData] });
        }
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { markers } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <CustomMap markers={markers} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any hints?